# Why does the node documentation list this opening bracket before the comma when describing this function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why does the node documentation list this opening bracket before the comma when describing this function?

fs.createReadStream(path[, options])
fs.createWriteStream(path[, options])

Translates into this:
fs.readFile('/etc/passwd', 'utf-8', callback());

so why do they make it like this fs.createReadStream(path**[,** options])
and not like this fs.createReadStream(path, [options])

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4):

When you see something like this in the doc:

```
fs.createReadStream(path[, options])
```

It means that the `options` argument is optional.  It does not need to be passed.  So you can `fs.createReadStream()` in either of these two ways:

```
fs.createReadStream(somePath)
```

or

```
fs.createReadStream(somePath, {flags: "r"});
```

The brackets `[]` are a documentation convention that the argument is optional **and since the argument is optional, so is the comma that goes with it**.  That's why the commas is included inside the brackets.  The comma is part of the optional part.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between:

```
fs.createReadStream(path[, options])
```

and

```
fs.createReadStream(path, [options])
```

The first means that if you don't pass in the options then you don't put the comma. It means that the following are valid:

```
fs.createReadStream(path);
fs.createReadStream(path, 'utf-8');
```

The second means that if you don't pass in the options you cannot leave out the comma. It means that the following are valid:

```
fs.createReadStream(path,); // <---------------- NOTE THE COMMA
fs.createReadStream(path, 'utf-8');
```

Obviously this is wrong. Therefore the documentation correctly put the optional signifier `[]` around the comma.

This convention comes form a long tradition of unix man (manual) pages.

Answer (score 0):

This is a convention for saying that the options argument is optional.
Both call are valid:

```
 fs.createReadStream(onlyPath);
 fs.createReadStream(somePath, someOptions);
```